How to customize Django Oscar category_tree template tag and remove pk from category URLs?
I'm working on an eCommerce project using Django Oscar, and I've run into an issue that I can't seem to solve. My goal is to customize the category URLs to only use slugs instead of both slug and pk, but I'm having trouble implementing this. Here's what I've done so far:

What I Want to Achieve:
I want to remove the pk from the category URLs in Django Oscar. Right now, my URLs look like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/category/metal-detectors_2/
I would like them to look like this:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/metal-detectors/

My Setup:



I'm using a forked catalogue app from Django Oscar, where I'm making my customizations.
I have a custom template categories.html in which I am trying to loop through categories and their child categories.
I have created a custom template tag category_tree in a templatetags folder under the catalogue app to handle category rendering.


Problem:
I am using the {% category_tree as tree_categories %} template tag to render categories, but it seems to be failing due to the use of pk in the URL construction. I want to modify it to only rely on the category_slug. However, I keep getting the following error:
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'category' with keyword arguments '{'category_slug': 'metal-detectors', 'pk': 2}' not found.

Here is part of the category_tree tag in my custom category_tags.py:
@register.simple_tag(name="category_tree")
def get_annotated_list(depth=None, parent=None):
    # Logic to retrieve categories
    # ...
    info = CheapCategoryInfo(
        node,
        url=node._get_absolute_url(tree_slug),  # Uses both slug and pk
        num_to_close=[],
        level=node_depth - start_depth,
    )
    annotated_categories.append(info)

What I’ve Tried:
I modified the get_absolute_url method in the Category model like this to try to remove pk:
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(
        "catalogue:category",
        kwargs={"category_slug": self.slug},  # Removed pk here
    )


I also customized my urls.py to remove pk from the URL pattern:
re_path(r'^(?P<category_slug>[\w-]+)/$', CustomProductCategoryView.as_view(), name='category') 
I'm trying to loop through the categories in categories.html like this:
{% load category_tags %}
<ul class="filter-categories__list">
    {% category_tree as tree_categories %}
    {% for category in tree_categories %}
        <li>{{ category.name }} - URL: {{ category.get_absolute_url }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>


Question:
How can I properly modify Django Oscar to remove the pk from the category URLs and only use the category_slug?
Is there a better approach to customizing the category_tree template tag to achieve this?
Any guidance would be appreciated! I'm relatively new to Django Oscar, so a beginner-friendly explanation would be very helpful.
Thanks in advance!
